# find corresponding dates in matlab

Tags: matlab, date

what is the best way of finding which dates are consistent among differnet variables. For example:

```
a = 
    2010-04-23 12:45
    2010-04-23 13:00    
    2010-04-23 13:15    
    2010-04-23 13:30    
    2010-04-23 13:45    
    2010-04-23 14:00
    2010-04-23 14:15

b = 
        2010-04-23 12:45
        2010-04-23 13:00    
        2010-04-23 13:15    
        2010-04-23 13:30    
        2010-04-23 13:45    
        2010-04-23 14:00
        2010-04-23 14:15
```

should return

```
c = 
      1
      1
      1
      1
      1
      1
      1
```

where both a and b are character strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `a` and `b` are cell arrays of strings, then you can just use:

```
c = strcmp(a, b)
```

You would define `a = {date_a1; date_a2; ...}` and `b = {date_b1; date_b2; ...}` using that syntax to build a cell of strings. You reference an element in a cell almost the same way as you would an array. If you want the third result of `c`, you would type `c{3}`.

[Documentation on strcmp here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html).

Comment: @Shaun314 makes an excellent point about converting the strings to datenums. That would be a more robust way of doing it. Furthermore, if the two vectors are of different lengths then see [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072780/find-same-datetime-in-arrays-of-different-lengths) about using `ismember` or `intersect`.

Answer (score 2):

Engineero is correct assuming they are exactly the same format.

I read your question as you having dates of different formats, so 4-25-13 and 04.25.2013 would also return a 1 (for the same date)

In this case, store the datenum of each str in a vector `datesA(i) = datenum(a{i})`, repeat for your B cell array, and then compare the vectors `c=(A==B)` to get your result