# find same datetime in arrays of different lengths

Tags: arrays, matlab, date

Consider the following arrays of julian dates

```
Jday1 = datenum('2011-01-01 00:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM'):60/(60*24):...
    datenum('2011-12-31 23:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM');
Jday2 = datenum('2011-04-01 00:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM'):60/(60*24):...
    datenum('2011-12-31 23:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM');
Jday3 = datenum('2011-02-06 00:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM'):60/(60*24):...
    datenum('2011-12-31 22:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM');
```

which are all of different length and have different time within them.

How would it be possible to find which dates are the same in the 3 arrays i.e. return the index of the consistent dateTime between all of the arrays?

I know I could use strcmp if they were the same size but what would I do if they are of different lengths as in the example? Also, strcmp would be an issue here due to the number of arrays being 3 not 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `intersect`:

```
common_dates = intersect(intersect(Jday1, Jday2), Jday3);
```

or if you also need the indices (based on a comment below by @Robert P., notice the change in the position of inner `intersect`):

```
[common_dates, idx] = intersect(Jday1, intersect(Jday2, Jday3));
```

**UPDATE**

If you have multiple arrays to intersect, write a small function to handle the job:

```
function varargout = intersectn(varargin)
narginchk(2, Inf);
nargoutchk(0, 2);
x = varargin{nargin}; 
for i = nargin-1:-1:1
    [x, idx] = intersect(varargin{i}, x); 
end
if nargout > 1, varargout{2} = idx; end
if nargout > 0, varargout{1} = x; else disp(x); end
```

Comment: +1, 2 seconds ahead of me... =P You can use the additional outputs of intersect to get the indices in Jday3..

Comment: Great, thanks. So, if you had say another Jday vector, could you use the same procedure as [common_dates, idx] = intersect(intersect(intersect(Jday1, Jday2), Jday3),Jday4); Some function similar to the merge function in R would be great here.

Comment: @Kate I added a small function that can handle unlimited number of intersections. You can add more bells and whistles to the function as necessary (checking for input parameter type, ...)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are storing your arrays as datenums and not strings, you could just compare them with `Compare = (Jday1 == Jday2)` and so on. This only works if the two vectors are the same length.

If the vectors are of different lengths, you could use `Compare = ismember(Jday1, Jday2)` to return an array the same size as `Jday1` with a 1 (true) at each index `i` where `Jday1(i)` can be found in the set `Jday2`.

[Documentation on ismember can be found here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html)

Finally, if you just want to return the indices where one list equals another, try `find(ismember(Jday1, Jday2))`.